# VB.Net - Serializing a list property

Tags: vb.net, list, serialization, properties

I've created three classes:

cLesson
cStage
cActivity

Right now, I'm experimenting with serialising list properties and have the following code for two of my classes setup:

cLesson.vb

```
<Serializable()> _
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlInclude(GetType(List(Of cStage)))> _
Public Class cLesson
    Private lStages As New List(Of cStage)

    Public Sub addStage(sStage As String)
        Dim oStage As New cStage

        oStage.Title = sStage

        lStages.Add(oStage)
    End Sub

    Public Sub listStages()
        For Each oStage In lStages
            MsgBox(oStage.Title)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

cStage.vb

```
<Serializable> _
Public Class cStage
    Private sTitle As String

    Public Property Title() As String
        Get
            Return sTitle
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            sTitle = Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Form1.vb - Serialise Calls

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim xml_serializer As New Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(cLesson))

    'Word document pointers
    Dim pDoc As String

    'Open master document
    Dim fdFile As SaveFileDialog = New SaveFileDialog

    fdFile.Title = "Save Reading Resource"
    fdFile.Filter = "Dat Files|*.dat"
    fdFile.RestoreDirectory = True

    If fdFile.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        pDoc = fdFile.FileName
        Dim stream_writer As New StreamWriter(pDoc, False)

        Try
            xml_serializer.Serialize(stream_writer, oLesson)
            stream_writer.Close() ' close the file
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.InnerException.ToString)
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

However, when I run this program, I'm not getting the list property appearing in the XML.

In the end, I want a lesson with a list of stages, each stage of which can have a list of activities.

Any advice would be great appreciated. I've looked online a lot and haven't been able to find anything to help.

### UPDATE 1

Making the list public allows it to be serialised. However, I'd prefer it to be private.

Public lStages As New List(Of cStage)

Comment: Try GetType(List(Of cStage))

Comment: An embarrassing mistake - However still not working

Answer (score -1, accepted):

XML Serialization works only on fields and properties marked as `Public`. Quoting the official documentatin article [Introducing XML Serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/introducing-xml-serialization):

> XML serialization serializes only the public fields and property values of an object into an XML stream.
>
> (...)
>
> XML serialization does not convert methods, indexers, private fields, or read-only properties (except read-only collections). To serialize all an object's fields and properties, both public and private, use the DataContractSerializer instead of XML serialization.

Thus you can switch to the [`DataContractSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer?view=netframework-4.7.2) to serialize private fields as well, but for it to work with regular XML Serialization (which supports XML attributes) the only way would be to change your field's declaration to:

```
Public lStages As New List(Of cStage)
```

Comment: Thanks. Should have spotted that one.

Comment: I may try creating a public property later, but it seems difficult to construct one to meet relevant needs. I will probably just keep the list public and write the functions I need.

Comment: @PaulHaydock : As you preferred to have it `Private`, see the duplicate I suggested in a comment on your question as well.

Comment: Thanks Vincent - Help much appreciated

Comment: @PaulHaydock : Glad I could help!

Comment: Why the downvote? My answer addresses the issue in the question and suggests two different ways of solving it depending on what the OP needs.